# method throws NPE but there is never an empty or null value in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the method which throws the NPE:

```
public void removeItemsbyBadWords() {
    String[] arrBadWords = settings.getBadWords();
    for(int i = 0;i < arrBadWords.length;++i) {
        String filter = ":contains("+arrBadWords[i]+")";
        Elements ele =  newsHeadlines.select(filter);
        if (ele != null && ele.size() > 0){
            for(Iterator<Element> iter = ele.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
               iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ArrayList `ele` is declared as an object variable and it is initialized by a method which is run before this method. I don't know why my method throws a NPE.

This is what FindBugs says about my method:

```
Bug: Read of unwritten field newsHeadlines in Client.removeItemsbyBadWords()

 The program is dereferencing a field that does not seem to ever have a non-null value written to it. Unless the field is initialized via some mechanism not seen by the analysis, dereferencing this value will generate a null pointer exception.  

Rank: Scary (8), 
confidence: Normal

Pattern: NP_UNWRITTEN_FIELD 

Type: NP, 
Category: CORRECTNESS (Correctness)<hr size="1" />

XML output:
<BugInstance type="NP_UNWRITTEN_FIELD" priority="2" rank="8" abbrev="NP" category="CORRECTNESS" first="25"> <Class classname="Client"> <SourceLine classname="Client" sourcefile="Client.java" sourcepath="Client.java"/> </Class> <Method classname="Client" name="removeItemsbyBadWords" signature="()V" isStatic="false"> <SourceLine classname="Client" start="146" end="156" startBytecode="0" endBytecode="276" sourcefile="Client.java" sourcepath="Client.java"/> </Method> <Field classname="Client" name="newsHeadlines" signature="Lorg/jsoup/select/Elements;" isStatic="false"> <SourceLine classname="Client" sourcefile="Client.java" sourcepath="Client.java"/> </Field> <SourceLine classname="Client" start="149" end="149" startBytecode="44" endBytecode="44" sourcefile="Client.java" sourcepath="Client.java"/> <SourceLine classname="Client" start="149" end="149" startBytecode="44" endBytecode="44" sourcefile="Client.java" sourcepath="Client.java"/> </BugInstance> <hr size="1" />

At Client.java:[line 149]
In method Client.removeItemsbyBadWords()
Field Client.newsHeadlines
```

I had a NPE with my method I use to initialize the ArrayList but that was related to not using an iterator for going through the list and removing some items.

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Client.removeItemsbyBadWords(Client.java:149)
    at Client$1.actionPerformed(Client.java:68)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you print the value of newsHeadlines

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot it @andy. I will do it now.

Comment: @Nivedita there seem to be no value assigned but why?

Comment: You are never calling `.next()` on your iterator. If you try to remove the same element twice, I guess it will throw null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `for` loop, you always try to remove the same element. You must call `iter.next()` at the end of the loop, to place iterator on the next element:

```
for(Iterator<Element> iter = ele.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()) {
    iter.remove();
}
```

Comment: It is still causing a NPE at the ele = ... line.

Comment: ah, ok. So are you shure you assign a value to newsHeadlines?

Comment: I accepted your answer because it helped and was right but the problem was at a very other spot. This has been a side effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FindBugs is telling you that `newsHeadlines` field is never assigned a value. Calling `newsHeadlines.select` therefore results in NPE.